# Динамическое изменение блоков background-а в бекенде

Tags: php, html, css, ruby-on-rails

К примеру, есть верстка, в которой дабы работало красиво и кроссбраузерно большинство картинок задано через свойства `сss background-image: url("...")`, указан `cover`, `position`. Весь контент на странице динамический. Например вывод новостей, или есть много страниц, у которых один и тот-же стиль, но должны быть разные картинки в зависимости от контента страницы (остальной стиль одинаковый).

Так сделано потому что просто вставить `<img src="">` и задать ему желанные свойства, чтобы картинка занимала всю поверхность блока и не деформировалась без костылей, очень проблематично.

Как динамически заменить `url` картинки в `css`?

Костыль - сделать джаваскриптом на клиенте - не предлагайте, так как это значит притянуть одну большущую картинку, потом на клиенте понять, что это не то, что вам нужно и притянуть еще одну большую картинку, вставив поправку непосредственно в `html`. Вариант вставить картинку через тег `style` непосредственно в `html`, тоже не очень красивый - хотя более интересный, чем джаваскрипт, для этого варианта есть одно но - зовут его ИЕ8, который мало того не понимает, что там написано, просто не зная `background-size: cover` и другие, картинку он вообще может брать из исходного стиля. В результате у вас может получиться что-то подобное: `<div style="background-image: url("../img/exsample.png") ">....</div>`. Что, согласитесь, не очень красиво для `html`.

Как сделать, используя `php` или `ruby`, или поделитесь как вы это делаете на своем фреймворке?

Comment: не обязательно фоном делать ,  можно работать и с тегом img вот пример  https://jsfiddle.net/atlanta/vdkzxj9o/

Comment: Опишите нормально задачу и я вам подыщу решение. То, что вы хотите не совсем понятно и, возможно, имеет лучшее решение, чем вы представляете.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте несколько классов с разными бекграундами

```
.background-1 {
      url: ...
 }
.background-2 {
      url: ...
 }
.background-3 {
      url: ...
 }
```

Затем опишите создайте хелпер который будет возвращать нужный класс в зависимости от ваших условий, например так:

```
class MyCobtroller < ApplicationController
   attr_reader :background_class
   helper_method :background_class

   def action
     @background_class = 'background-1'
      ...
   end
 end
```

Далее в html используем метод.

```
 <div  class="<%= background_class %>"></div>
```

Comment: У меня в новостях 5000 картинок, вариант с беграундами непрокатит